# inputscope spanish decimal number

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I configura inputscope number in order to acept spanish decimal numbers? I need change "." by ","

phone regional settins is spanish.

this is my code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtCantdiad" Text="{Binding Cantidad, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterCulture=es-ES, StringFormat=N2}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                      Visibility="{Binding UsaUnidades}"  KeyUp="Canvas_KeyUp">
               <TextBox.InputScope>
                    <InputScope>
                        <InputScopeName NameValue="Number"/>
                    </InputScope>
                </TextBox.InputScope>
 </TextBox>
```

Thanks

Comment: If `Cantidad` is a numeric type (double or decimal) this should work as you are specifying the culture for the converter.

Answer (score 0):

I think replacing the comma by a dot in code would be the best approach, correct me if i am wrong,

PHP : `str_replace(",",".", $_POST['txtCantdiad']);`

C# : `txtCantdiad.Replace(",", ".");`